# Cambiar url en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ya hice mi app de **AngularJS** pero tengo un problema y creo que es muy pequeño, lo que pasa es que estoy utilizando un elemento **JSON** y dentro de sus parametros esta una propiedad llamada **url**

En la cual guarda cualquier url por ejemplo *www.youtube.com*, esta propiedad la quiero para poder hacer un href y que me redirija a la pagina deseada

Aquí el codigo, este es el archivo guardado en el proyecto.component.ts

```
var post = {
    nombre: "Youtube",
    url: "www.youtube.com",
    descripción: "Pagina de videos web"
  }
```

Aquí el component.html

```
<a href="{{post.url}}" target="blank">{{post.url}}</a>
```

Lo que quiero es que me redirija a http://www.youtube.com , pero la propiedad **href** me redirije a http://localhost:4200/www.youtube.com, lo que pasa es que la página por default al tener el routing, siempre me redirige a una página adentro y después del **4200/**, yo quiero que me redirija a una página completamente externa a la mia, gracias por ayudarme :D.

Comment: Gracias, disculpe por el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno te comentaré algunos puntos que tienes mal:

- La *data* debe ir contenida en un objeto, tu estructura esta mal puesto que tienes una especie de vector pero que también esta mal formado

**Vector**

```
let algo = [algo1, algo2, algo3, ......]
```

**Objeto**

```
let algo = {
    algo1: valor1,
    algo2: valor2,
    algo3: ......
}
```

- Debes colocar la URL real del destino al cual estás apuntando, es decir a tu código le hace falta:

  - Protocolo, que en este caso debe ser `HTTPS`

Te dejo el ejemplo funcional:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo :D</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="videitos">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank">{{post.nombre }}</a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>  
      let app = angular.module('app', [])
      
      app.controller('videitos', function($scope) {
        $scope.post = {
          nombre: "Youtube",
          url: "https://www.ejemplo.com/",
          descripción: "Pagina de videos web"
        }
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Referencia**

- [AngularJS $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya pude resovlerlo, gracias a ti :D